# Proper way for a Typescript (node:) import in electron browser app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, esbuild

I'm building a typescript project which runs in a browser.  Everything works great, have gotten far, but I have now imported an additional module which internally imports some things like so:

```
const path = await import("node:path");
const fs = await import("node:fs/promises");
```

This suddenly fails the build with the error:

*Could not resolve "node:path" You can mark the path "node:path" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also add ".catch()" here to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.*

```
Node version: v21.2.0
Npm version: 10.2.4
tsc Version 5.2.2
```

From my package.json, the build script is

```
tsc -skipLibCheck && node esbuild.config.mjs production && npm pack
```

I can modify esbuild.config.mjs to add an [external] for node:*, like so:

```
esbuild.build({
banner: {
    js: banner,
},
entryPoints: ['main.ts'],
bundle: true,
external: [
    'electron',
    'node:*',   <<<<ADDED
```

Doing this resolves the build-time error above, but however then later when the application runs, it encounters a CORS error trying to do the import, I guess literally thinking "node:fs/promises" is a url of some kind and trying to fetch from literally "node:fs/promises".

Because this is running in a browser, it is prevented by CORS, whether this says "node:" or not, I would guess.

I'm not a super typescript expert, but I assume this is because there is some compile-time step that needs to translate or redirect [node:fs/promises] to a local module.  I cannot update the external module to remove/change it saying import("node:fs/promises") => import("fs/promises"), for example.

I am expecting some way to use this third party module and when it does this *internally*...

```
const path = await import("node:path");
const fs = await import("node:fs/promises");
```

Either this is replaced at compile time with something different, or that there's a magic under-the-hood mechanism to allow it to get those modules (which I thought would be default available, but oh well), or some other technique I don't know about.

Any pointers on how to get around this?

Comment: See the [IPC documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc).